# plotting arrays in python upto a particular element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have a data file like this:

```
0.001  5.515e-01  1.056e+00  1.384e-01  1.273e+01  -1.808e-01  1.255e+01
0.002  2.335e-02  -1.100e-03  -8.850e-03  1.273e+01  -3.176e-01  1.241e+01
0.003  2.335e-02  -1.100e-03  -8.850e-03  1.273e+01  -3.177e-01  1.241e+01
0.004  2.335e-02  -1.101e-03  -8.851e-03  1.273e+01  -3.177e-01  1.241e+01
0.005  2.335e-02  -1.101e-03  -8.851e-03  1.273e+01  -3.177e-01  1.241e+01
0.006  2.335e-02  -1.102e-03  -8.851e-03  1.273e+01  -3.177e-01  1.241e+01
0.007  2.335e-02  -1.102e-03  -8.852e-03  1.273e+01  -3.177e-01  1.241e+01
...    ...          ...         ...        ...         ...        ...
```

where the 1st column is time, the last one is total energy, 2nd last is potential energy and 3rd last is kinetic energy. Now I want to plot these energies as function of time, but I do not want to plot the whole array at one go.

Rather I wish to choose a time and plot the energies upto that time and then again choose another time and plot the energies upto that time (starting always from t=0). The code I have written for that is given below:

```
from pylab import*
from numpy import*

data=loadtxt('500.txt')

t=data[:,0]
KE=data[:,-3]
PE=data[:,-2]
TE=data[:,-1]

t=0
while t<100:
    ke=KE[:t]
    time=t[:t]
    plot(time,ke)
    picname=temp+'e.png'
    savefig(picname)
    show()
    t=t+40
```

But it returns `File "energyprofile.py", line 14, in <module>
    time=t[:t]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. How can I get round this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't line 14 be time=time[:t]? t is a scalar, and you start with value 0. So at the start of line 14, you have t=0. Then you say time = t[:t], i.e. time = 0[:0]. Hence the attribute error.

Comment: Yeah you are almost right . I have found out why. Actually I have a array named `t`. Shouldn't have chosen the same name for a loop variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the loop variable name. There is already an array named `t`.

```
t=data[:,0]
```

So when the array index `t` is called inside the array `t`,

```
time=t[:t]
```

it returns the error. The problem is removed when the variable name is changed:

```
t1=0
while t1<100:
    ke=KE[:t1]
    time=t[:t1]
    plot(time,ke)
    picname=str(t1)+'e.png'
    savefig(picname)
    show()
    t=t+40
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no commas in the [slicing  notation for python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)

this here:

```
t=data[:,0]
KE=data[:,-3]
PE=data[:,-2]
TE=data[:,-1]
```

must be replaced by:

```
t=data[:0]
KE=data[:-3]
PE=data[:-2]
TE=data[:-1]
```

Comment: But the error occurs in the 14th line. I have added that to my error message. Also I tried with replacing the commas, but still it gives the same error-message.